# Polymer use Array for data binding

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have this dom-repeat template and I wonder how to pass an Array into attribute.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{headers}}">
          <span>{{item}}</span>
        </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    properties: {
      headers: Array
    }
  });
</script>
```

and then in an `index.html` file, I bind it like this:

```
<my-element headers="['abc', 'def']"></my-element>
```

I tried doing that but I nothing happened and I got the warning `Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch the double and single quotes. Polymer 1.0 requires correct JSON quotes, in 0.5 the reverse was accepted ([source](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#attr)).

```
<my-element headers='["abc", "def"]'></my-element>
```